# Access Data in the navigation controller

Tags: iphone

I have a controller1 which contains a view which contain many subviews ( Textfields,....).
I use a navigation controller. I push the controller1 and in this controller I push an other controller2.

My problem is to access the data of the controller1, for example I want to access the data of the textfield of my controller1 in the controller2.

How I can do this please ???

Thanks for your answers

Comment: certainly possible, but better use a data-model updated by those views and access the model from both of those views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using navigation controller you will have access of all the `viewcontrollers` you pushed on **navigation stack**. You can retreive any one of them using following code.

```
[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:<Here you need to take care of the correct index of your desired viewcontroller>];
```

*//above code will return viewcontroller at that index.*

for knowing correct index, use

```
NSLog(@"View Controllers : \n%@\n",[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By controller1 and controller2, I'll assume that you mean UIViewController. If that is what you mean, than just create IBOutlets of the objects that you want to access in the first UIViewController. Then `#import` the first UIViewController in your second UIViewController and then you can access the IBOutlets from there.

Next time please search as this is a fairly common question and has been answered numerous times all over the internet.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it's not what i want. Yes i know how to use properties but i want to access a specific viewcintroller in the stack of the navigation controller and i don't know how to do this

Comment: If you know which view controller you want to access before runtime then you can use my method. If you don't know which view controller then use Ravin's method.